# Create a file in xml.config format by replacing a couple of variables using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, syntax, automation, configuration

I have to create an xml.config file inside a directory to skip the registration part.
The idea is to define variables with username, user email and a string for the xml file in text format. Then I create a text file in the directory and add-contents of the string variable. Then I convert the contents of the text file to xml by using ConvertTo-XML and save it as .config file.

The string variable contains xml file contents along with two variables username and usermail. The text file is getting created, but they aren't being replaced. Here's the powershell code:

```
$excluded_users = ("packer", "Public", "systemprofile", "LocalService", "NetworkService", "CitrixTelemetryService")
                 

#Get Username, SID, and location of ntuser.dat for all users. Filtering execluded users.

$ProfileList = gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*' |
        Select  @{ name = "SID"; expression = { $_.PSChildName } },
        @{ name = "UserHive"; expression = { "$( $_.ProfileImagePath )\ntuser.dat" } },
        @{ name = "Username"; expression = { $_.ProfileImagePath -replace '^(.*[\\\/])', '' } } |
        Where-Object { $_.Username -notin $excluded_users }
$usern= $ProfileList.Username
$searcher = [adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$usern)"
$usermail = $searcher.FindOne().Properties.mail
$userxml= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <SourceTree.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="MainWindowWidth" serializeAs="String">
                <value>1201.3333333333333</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MainWindowHeight" serializeAs="String">
                <value>737.33333333333326</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MainWindowState" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Normal</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MainWindowLeft" serializeAs="String">
                <value>40</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MainWindowTop" serializeAs="String">
                <value>40</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="GitWhichOne" serializeAs="String">
                <value>1</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="AllowModifyConfigFiles" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="DefaultFullName" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Domain-COM\$(usern)</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="DefaultEmail" serializeAs="String">
                <value>$(usermail)</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="LastOpenTabIndex" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="AnonymousID" serializeAs="String">
                <value>f32d3160-f61d-4050-8cb4-e3e4670f9a1c</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="AgreedToEULA" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="AgreedToEULAVersion" serializeAs="String">
                <value>20160201</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="SSHClientType" serializeAs="String">
                <value>PuTTY</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ProxyServerMode" serializeAs="String">
                <value>OperatingSystem</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="HgWhichOne" serializeAs="String">
                <value>-1</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="EnableGitSupport" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="EnableHgSupport" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="HgPostPullAction" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Update</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MainWindowScreenDeviceName" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
            <setting name="AnalyticsHasAgreed" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="GitSystemPath" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\Program Files\Git</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="HgSystemPath" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
            <setting name="SidebarIsOpen" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="NotificationGettingStartedShown" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
        </SourceTree.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>'

New-Item -Path "C:\Users\$usern\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_yjhzxxhcu2ommegrdorjf3q1oqllqxiq\3.4.5.0" -ItemType directory -Force
    New-Item -Path "C:\Users\$usern\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_yjhzxxhcu2ommegrdorjf3q1oqllqxiq\3.4.5.0\user.txt" -Force
    Add-Content "C:\Users\$usern\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_yjhzxxhcu2ommegrdorjf3q1oqllqxiq\3.4.5.0\user.txt" $userxml
   
$userxmlconfig = Get-Content "C:\Users\$usern\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_yjhzxxhcu2ommegrdorjf3q1oqllqxiq\3.4.5.0\user.txt" | ConvertTo-XML

 New-Item -Path "C:\Users\$usern\AppData\Roaming\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_yjhzxxhcu2ommegrdorjf3q1oqllqxiq\3.4.5.0\user.config" -Force
 Add-Content "C:\Users\$usern\AppData\Roaming\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_yjhzxxhcu2ommegrdorjf3q1oqllqxiq\3.4.5.0\user.config" $userxmlconfig

 New-Item -Path "C:\Users\$usern\AppData\Roaming\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_yjhzxxhcu2ommegrdorjf3q1oqllqxiq\3.4.5.0" -ItemType directory -Force
    New-Item -Path "C:\Users\$usern\AppData\Roaming\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_yjhzxxhcu2ommegrdorjf3q1oqllqxiq\3.4.5.0\user.txt" -Force
    Add-Content "C:\Users\$usern\AppData\Roaming\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_yjhzxxhcu2ommegrdorjf3q1oqllqxiq\3.4.5.0\user.txt" $userxml
   
$userxmlconfig = Get-Content "C:\Users\$usern\AppData\Roaming\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_yjhzxxhcu2ommegrdorjf3q1oqllqxiq\3.4.5.0\user.txt" | ConvertTo-XML

 New-Item -Path "C:\Users\$usern\AppData\Roaming\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_yjhzxxhcu2ommegrdorjf3q1oqllqxiq\3.4.5.0\user.config" -Force
 Add-Content "C:\Users\$usern\AppData\Roaming\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_yjhzxxhcu2ommegrdorjf3q1oqllqxiq\3.4.5.0\user.config" $userxmlconfig
```

Comment: Change `$userxml= '<?xml  ...' ` to use double-quotes instead - `$userxml= "<?xml  ... "` Also fix the way you are using the variable in the string. `$(usermail)` should be `${usermail}` or `$($usermail)` "The type of quotes you use around the string makes a difference. A double quoted string allows the substitution but a single quoted string doesn't. There are times you want one or the other so you have an option." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.1#variable-substitution

Comment: or just `$usermail`.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Daniel.
I have replaced ' with " and other substitutions. The folders are created, but they are empty. Please check the script again and correct me, maybe I'm missing something somewhere.

Comment: There are quite a few things that need to be corrected.  First, I need to know what is your intention with `$userxmlconfig = Get-Content "${localPath}\user.txt" | ConvertTo-Xml`?  The content of user.txt is already in xml format so `ConvertTo-Xml` is not needed and is actually causing issues.  It looks like user.txt and user.config should contain the same content - the xml in `$userxml`?

Comment: Yes, the contents of user.txt and user.config are the same. The reason I tried ConvertTo-Xml is to convert the text format to XML format and then save it as user.config. I could be wrong.
But, now when I execute the script, I have a .txt file getting created with substituted variables (just how we want it). There is also a user.config file created and looks like this:
``` 
System.Xml.XmlDocument 
```
This is not what we want.

Answer (score 0):

Your first big issue was this line `$usern= $ProfileList.Username`.  `$ProfileList` is an array of profiles found so `$usern` was being assigned an array of usernames.  I've added a foreach loop to loop through each profile in `$ProfileList` and assign only one username.

Second issue was with `$userxml`.  We need the text to be in double-quotes to allow variable expansion.  Since there are already double-quotes in the xml code we can use a [here string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1#here-strings) `@" ... "@`

At the end you were using `ConvertTo-Xml` on text that was already in xml format.  Removed this.  Also it looks user.config was being created twice so I commented out the second time.

Without too much more explanation, I think the following should work.  I've added a few comments in the code.

```
$excluded_users = ('packer', 'Public', 'systemprofile', 'LocalService', 'NetworkService', 'CitrixTelemetryService')

#Get Username, SID, and location of ntuser.dat for all users. Filtering excluded users.

$ProfileList = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*' |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            SID      = $_.PSChildName
            UserHive = "$( $_.ProfileImagePath )\ntuser.dat"
            Username = $_.ProfileImagePath -replace '^(.*[\\\/])', ''
        }
    } | Where-Object { $_.Username -notin $excluded_users }

# Add foreach to loop through each $ProfileList
$ProfileList | ForEach-Object {
    $username = $_.Username
    $searcher = [adsisearcher]"(samaccountname=$username)"
    $usermail = $searcher.FindOne().Properties.mail

    # Change to here string with double-quotes to allow variable expansion
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1#here-strings
    $userxml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <SourceTree.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="MainWindowWidth" serializeAs="String">
                <value>1201.3333333333333</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MainWindowHeight" serializeAs="String">
                <value>737.33333333333326</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MainWindowState" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Normal</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MainWindowLeft" serializeAs="String">
                <value>40</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MainWindowTop" serializeAs="String">
                <value>40</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="GitWhichOne" serializeAs="String">
                <value>1</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="AllowModifyConfigFiles" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="DefaultFullName" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Domain-COM\$username</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="DefaultEmail" serializeAs="String">
                <value>$usermail</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="LastOpenTabIndex" serializeAs="String">
                <value>0</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="AnonymousID" serializeAs="String">
                <value>f32d3160-f61d-4050-8cb4-e3e4670f9a1c</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="AgreedToEULA" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="AgreedToEULAVersion" serializeAs="String">
                <value>20160201</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="SSHClientType" serializeAs="String">
                <value>PuTTY</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ProxyServerMode" serializeAs="String">
                <value>OperatingSystem</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="HgWhichOne" serializeAs="String">
                <value>-1</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="EnableGitSupport" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="EnableHgSupport" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="HgPostPullAction" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Update</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="MainWindowScreenDeviceName" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
            <setting name="AnalyticsHasAgreed" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="GitSystemPath" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\Program Files\Git</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="HgSystemPath" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
            <setting name="SidebarIsOpen" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="NotificationGettingStartedShown" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
        </SourceTree.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
"@

    $localPath = "C:\Users\$username\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_yjhzxxhcu2ommegrdorjf3q1oqllqxiq\3.4.5.0"
    $roamingPath = "C:\Users\$username\AppData\Roaming\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_yjhzxxhcu2ommegrdorjf3q1oqllqxiq\3.4.5.0"

    New-Item -Path "${localPath}" -ItemType directory -Force    # Create local path
    New-Item -Path "${localPath}\user.txt" -Force               # Create empty user.txt file in local path
    Add-Content "${localPath}\user.txt" $userxml                # Fill user.txt file with content of $userxml

    # $userxmlconfig = Get-Content "${localPath}\user.txt" | ConvertTo-Xml  

    New-Item -Path "${roamingPath}" -ItemType directory -Force  # Move folder creation up

    New-Item -Path "${roamingPath}\user.config" -Force
    Add-Content "${roamingPath}\user.config" $userxml           # Change to $userxml

    New-Item -Path "${roamingPath}\user.txt" -Force
    Add-Content "${roamingPath}\user.txt" $userxml

    # $userxmlconfig = Get-Content "${roamingPath}\user.txt" | ConvertTo-Xml

    # New-Item -Path "${roamingPath}\user.config" -Force
    # Add-Content "${roamingPath}\user.config" $userxmlconfig     

}
```